# 'for' loop support in Kafka KStreams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

i need to know how to use 'for' loop in my kafka KStreams line...below is my 'for' loop which need to be included in the KStreams

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6 ; i++) {
            try {
                textlines.flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.split("\\},\\{")));
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

and my KStreams loooks like

```
KStream<String, String> textlines = builder.stream("intopic");
KStream<String, String> mstream = textlines
                .mapValues(value -> value.replace("[","" ) )
```

how to add my above 'for' loop into my KStreams

Comment: What is the exact purpose of this for loop ? KStream object is just a way to build a topology that will run in other threads afterward (after the .start() call). In your code you are just adding 6 times the same processor to your topology and the sleeping part will have no effect on the stream execution, il will just retard the topology building.

Comment: @nbchn ok...the thing is i have used value.split in 'for' loop to split my data....so whenever my data get split it should sleep for about 10ms...this is because i need my data to come one after the other, if u need more details let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the thing is i have used value.split in 'for' loop to split my data....so whenever my data get split it should sleep for about 10ms...this is because i need my data to come one after the other

From what you say you want ordering.  To achieve ordering you don't need to `sleep`.  It will just work.  The Kafka Streams WordCount example, which I assume your code is based on, works in the same way: it also uses `flatMapValues`, and the lambda passed into flat map is splitting text lines into words.

Unless I and others misinterpret your question (in which case you should perhaps clarify your question further), I think you are unnecessarily complicating your code.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817572/adding-for-loop-with-delay-in-kafka-streams) u can take a look at this example...this is what exactly i need to do...

Comment: And it is the same answer.  Just use `flatMapValues`, which will ensure that data will come one-by-one.